# Android tutorial error: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I have been following this tutorial, but I have two errors, both "R cannot be resolved to a variable". I have made android apps (easy ones) in the past, and I remember this problem being fixed by checking whether or not I have an import R statement (which I don't) and whether or not the project has been cleaned before being built again (I cleaned it and I still get the error).  I am at a loss as to what to do. Thanks!

*I also want to mention I did see the thread of the same title with 170 hits, and the solution of "delete the import R statement" does not apply to my problem (I don't think)
Thanks again

All code is straight from the link above, but here it is for convenience

activity_my_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyFirstActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MyFirstActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_first);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_first, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Menu Settings</string>
</resources>
```

edit: When I clean the project, I get this message in the Console:

> [2012-06-29 11:12:38 - MyFirstApp] W/ResourceType( 6140): Bad XML
>   block: header size 91 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
>   [2012-06-29 11:12:38 - MyFirstApp]
>   C:\Users\zhong\workspace\eclipse\MyFirstApp\res\menu\activity_my_first.xml:2:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').

edit: added a line to layout xml file `<string name="menu_settings">Menu Settings</string>`
Fixed cleaning project errors, but I still can't run the project from the two R errors.

Comment: Yes. I just noticed there were errors when I cleaned. I edited the original post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm working my way through the same example, and had the same (or very similar) problem.

Finally I noticed that there was a tiny little red x on the manifest.xml.
Sure enough, it was complaining about this:

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_world" >
```

So I added:

```
<string name="title_activity_hello_world">Hello World</string>
```

to strings.xml and now it works.

Comment: They explain this underneath to be fair!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while following the tutorial.
Cleaning the project or cleaning the imports did not solve the problem.

How the problem was (simply) solved : I quit Eclipse and relaunched it.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible things

The package name specified in the Android Manifest isn't the same as the in the Java files.

Or, your IDE hasn't generated the R.java file in the gen/ folder. Try building again (despite the error) and it will usually clear it up.

Basically the R.java file is generated for you and in the same package so you can refer to it as simply R.

Answer (score 1):

I had `android:text="@string/button_send"`
Which gave the error: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/button_send').`

I tried to solve the error using the tuturial. But the tutorial fails to tell me to write all the lines required one by one.  So I miss to write `"<string name="button_send">Send</string>"` in the strings.xml.

After adding the previous line the error disappear!  Which I believe is something similar to the original problem in this thread.

So if I had copied the whole lines from the given tutorial it may had not happened, but by typing our-self is how I think is the best way of learning.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

go to your `project->res->menu`  than open the `XML` file there and delete this line:

```
android:title="@string/menu_settings"
```

I deleted it and it start to work,after 3 hours of the same warning in the problem section.

It even make sense when you read it, "at `title` with value `@string/menu_settings`"

Answer (score 0):

Pleas confirm there is no error in

1- Project folder 
2- Problem View of eclipse
3- Console 
4- error log     as in image 
[image]

Comment: There are two errors: 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_first); and 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_first, menu); ~::~ both say R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: are you have R.java in gen folder of project?

Comment: so there must be error due to which R.java no get generated... is there any error on console while building project

Comment: The build buttons are greyed out. However there is no error when I do clean (clean seems to automatically build after cleaning)

Comment: gr8.. finally you got the problem now refresh your project clean that and run ....see if not run find the error again

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to

1. Clean your project Project-->Clean
2. The /res directory  doesn't contain errors (some files will show up
   with a red icon on the file explorer)
3. Your imports doesn't contain this line `import android.R;`
4. Check that in AndroidManifest.xml, the attribute package has the
   correct value. `<manifestxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="your.correct.package.name"`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259974/1538785

Seems like eclipse likes to add an import line to java files for no reason. Go onto your java file, hit ctrl+shift+o and all the import statements will appear. Delete the line that says import andriod.R

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Project, select "Android Tools" > "Add Support Library" > "Android Support Library, revision 11" > "Install"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was on 64-bit Linux, and the required 32-bit libraries were not installed, meaning that the build tools could not generate R.java.

Running this command, then cleaning the project, fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the executables (aapt etc.) in sdk/build-tools/android-xyz/* are executable if you are running the default download on your Linux box...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to do the first tutorial. To get the app to run I edited MainActivity.java so it looked like this

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}